# action listener not working in mac os x

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans, graphics

I cannot compile the actionlistener using netbeans IDE and mac OSX. I m a beginner please help. It says that incompatible types. I have tried to implement the ActionListerner interface but received no luck. I cant understand what to do.

```
package test1;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf= new JFrame("xyz");
        JTextField jt= new JTextField("hello!!");
        jt.setBounds(200,200,50,90);
        JButton jb= new JButton("click");
        jb.setBounds(50,100,100,100);

        jf.add(jb);
        jf.add(jt);
        jf.setSize(400,500);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        //this line is not compiling and showing error

        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"working");
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does the error say?

Comment: Apart from missing a closing brace at the end, I can compile your code without any such problem.